# Why can't I push a new blog comment to the Django database (foreign.key model relationship)

Tags: django

I would like to create a new comment object if the user submits his comment. Along with the model form content I deliver the link to a gif that is rendered outside the form in the Html. The view is triggered via an async AJAX call.

Currently, it throws this error:

```
IntegrityError at /post_comment/

C:\Users\Jonas\Desktop\finsphere\finsphere\blog\views.py in post_comment
    comment.save() …
▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
comment 
Error in formatting: TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)
gif None
name None
post_id None
request <WSGIRequest: GET '/post_comment/'>
text None
```

**views.py**

```
def post_comment(request):

    # Assign search term
    gif = request.GET.get('gif_src')
    name = request.GET.get('name')
    text = request.GET.get('text')
    post_id = request.GET.get('post_id')


    comment = Comment(
        post=post_id,
        name=name,
        text=text,
        gif=gif)

    comment.save()

    return render(request, 'post.html', comment)
```

**models.py**

```
# Comment Model
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    gif = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    approved_comment = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def approve(self):
        self.approved_comment = True
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

**forms.py**

```
# Blog Post Comment Form
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('name', 'text',)
```

**Async ajax view call**

```
(function($) {
  $('.comment-button').on('click', function(e) {

      // Assign the contents
      var gif_src = $('#giphy-out').children().attr('src');
      var name = $('#form-name').text();
      var text = $('#form-text').text();
      var post_id = $('#post_id_hidden').text();

      // Prevent a new page load
      e.preventDefault();

      // Request the gifs via Django view
      $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        async: true,
        url: '/post_comment/',
        data: {
            'gif_src': gif_src,
            'name': name,
            'text': text,
            'post_id': post_id,
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': window.CSRF_TOKEN // from blog.html
        },

        success: function(response) {
            console.log('Comment posted')
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
          // shit happens friends!
        }
    });
  });
}(jQuery));
```

**Update to Willems answer**

Now it throws this error:

```
[2020-06-28 13:52:47,513] log: ERROR - Internal Server Error: /post_comment/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\http.py", line 40, in inner
    return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\Desktop\finsphere\finsphere\blog\views.py", line 245, in post_comment
    comment = Comment.objects.create(
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 431, in create
    obj = self.model(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 482, in __init__
    _setattr(self, field.name, rel_obj)
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 214, in __set__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Cannot assign "'8'": "Comment.post" must be a "Post" instance.
[28/Jun/2020 13:52:47] "POST /post_comment/ HTTP/1.1" 500 19080
```

Comment: A GET request is not supposed to have side effects. Furthermore in a GET request, the data is passed through the URL (the querystring): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Querystring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A GET request is not supposed to have any side effects, as specified in the [*HTTP/1.1 method definitions*](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.3). Furthermore for a GET request the data is submitted through the [*query string* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Querystring), the part after the question mark (`?`), not as request payload.

```
from django.views.decorators.http import require_http_methods

@require_http_methods(['POST'])
def post_comment(request):
    gif = request.POST['gif_src']
    name = request.POST['name']
    text = request.POST['text']
    post_id = request.POST['post_id']
    comment = Comment.objects.create(
        post_id=post_id,
        name=name,
        text=text,
        gif=gif
    )
    return render(request, 'post.html', {'comment': comment})
```

In the AJAX call, you then make a POST request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    async: true,
    url: '/post_comment/',
    data: {
        gif_src: gif_src,
        name: name,
        text: text,
        post_id: post_id,
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: window.CSRF_TOKEN
    },
    success: function(response) {
        console.log('Comment posted')
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        // shit happens friends!
    }
});
```

You furthermore should make sure the variables like `gif_src`, `name`, etc. exist at the JavaScript side, and are not `null`.

Comment: thank you for the insights. I adapted your solution and get a related error now, I posted it to the initial issue.

Comment: @Jonas: ah, it should be `post_id=post_id` instead of `post=post_id`.